# set theoretic equality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be any map. I am trying to prove the following:

$f(f^{-1}(A) \cap B)=A \cap f(B)$.

I can prove containment in one direction:

We have

$x \in f^{-1}(A) \iff f(x) \in A$ and

$x \in B \implies f(x) \in f(B)$.

So

$f(f^{-1}(A) \cap B) \subset A \cap f(B)$.

I don't know how to do the other direction.

The context is that is part of the proof of the push-pull formula on pg. 30 of the book 3264 by Eisenbud and Harris. The book is about intersection theory, but it claims that this is a set-theoretic equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the other direction take $y\in A\cap f(B)$. This means that $y\in A$ and that there exists $x\in B$ such that $y=f(x)$. This $x$ is also in $f^{-1}(A)$ since $f(x)=y\in A$, so that $x\in f^{-1}(A)\cap B$. Thus $y=f(x)\in f(f^{-1}(A)\cap B)$.

Comment: Oops. For some reason I had convinced myself that there might not be an $x \in B$ such that $y=f(x)$. Thanks.